# How to set a fix string at first of QLineEdit?

Tags: c++, qt, qlineedit

It's possible to set a fix string at first of `QLineEdit`? something like this:
[image]

Which in here `$` is constant and user could not remove or edit it.

Comment: Did you look at `QLineEdit::inputMask()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the input mask in the object: e.g.

```
ui->lineEdit->setInputMask("$ 000.000.000.000 ");
```

will look like

[image]

Comment: Can be combined with  validator, i believe i used that for IP address input